# Marketing and publicizing CSE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In light of Robert's recent comment, we need outreach.  I just wanted to collect a group of targets.  I'm aware of

- http://reddit.com/r/compsci
- http://reddit.com/r/CSEducation
- https://edu.google.com/cs/explore.html (getting ourselves listed)

What are other areas in which we can do outreach?

**Edit on 6/11/17:** the number of new users has slowed over the last few days, so we need to act again to keep things moving.  Should I go after the three targets above during private beta, or once public beta starts?

Comment: I have mentioned [chief delphi](https://www.chiefdelphi.com/forums/portal.php) in chat. It's a forum for FRC   (FIRST Robotics Competition) teams. That community will be willing to make this site rise.

Comment: Why wait until public beta?

Comment: Good point - this thread was older.  We have not been waiting at all.  We just expect to have even more success once we're in public beta.

Comment: IN RE: 6/11/17 edit, The sooner the better. Private Beta not withstanding. Some may turn aside at the login wall, some will come through anyway. Make the links to the main site, and let SE mechanisms do the Area 51 redirect. Avoids the need to change the links when we do go to Public Beat.

Answer (score 4):

I posted to:

- Systers, a huge email list for women in CS.
- Facebook group Computer Science Education: Researchers & Practitioners
- Google+ groups CS First and Silicon Valley CSTA
- SIGCSE (via a friend)

I tweeted with unsuccessful retweet requests to:

- [CSTeachingTips](https://twitter.com/CSTeachingTips)
- [Code.org](https://twitter.com/codeorg)

I would like for someone to send announcements to members of CSTA.

Comment: Were you responsible for today's explosion of users?  Today was amazing!

Comment: (BTW - if you're interested in the health and development of the site, you should also consider joining us in the [cseducators chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 3):

I've mentioned the site already on the following communities:

- AP Teacher Community - AP CS A
- AP Teacher Community - AP CSP
- CS50 AP Teacher Discussion Board
- Twitter - hashtags #apcsp #apcsa #cs50ap

There are probably more hashtags to add such as #edtechchat or #cs4all. I will also be attending a week-long AP institute in July for AP CS A, so I will be mentioning it there every chance I get. I'm working on curriculum development for a Raspberry Pi course, which will lead me to the teacher side of the Raspberry Pi Forums where I will link to this community as well.

While posting on forums is helpful, finding ways to make that more personal invitation -- even if that personal invitation is digital -- will be key. Individual recommendations go a long way.

Comment: I'm not on Twitter, but I 100% agree about the personalization.  Asking someone to comment on a question in their wheelhouse, or pointing them to a resource that they might individually find useful can work wonders